# Google Play Services Player image url

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to get the image Url of my Player ( com.google.android.gms.games.Player ). Unfortunately, all the existing methods return with Uri.

So I want this (zzac on the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbTKp.jpg) ) :
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4xKyR2m7cv2i3eMq-4B8tZpud0785b5jyHmQE7zLYE84ifQsAwWLyb6BWD_0OaA0Kow=s240-ns

Not this ( zzcj on the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbTKp.jpg) ) :
content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/ae4fb834/670

Answer (score 0):

There's a depricated method called hiResImageUrl.